# How to use ActiveRecord to get a list of records which have 2 related records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, arel

Say I have 2 models:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses
end
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
end
```

I want to get all people who have exactly 2 addresses.  Is there an easy ActiveRecord/Arel way of doing this with a subquery?  I don't want to use a counter_cache to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me (using Rails 3, PostGreSQL):

```
Patient.joins(:interventions).group('patients.id').having('count(patient_interventions.id) = 2')
```

**In your case, the following should return the Persons with exactly 2 Addresses:**

```
Person.includes(:addresses)
      .select('persons.*')
      .group('persons.id')
      .having('count(addresses.id) = 2')
# Note use :joins instead of :includes if you don't want the addresses data
```

Comment: I'd add `select('people.*')` to that query to get rid of address-related attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by @MrYoshiji is good, but sometimes you might prefer to do two queries.  Another approach:

```
person_ids = Address.select('person_id, count(person_id) as cnt').group('person_id').having('cnt = 2').pluck(:person_id)
Person.find person_ids
```